# intellij GWT debug configuration

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, gwt

How can I override the default server **intellij's GWT debug configuration** ? 
Intellij takes a Jetty as default server but I want it to use a jboss server.

I tried with the Jetty server, But I've got something like a authentication error ...

[image]

Does someone know either how to override the default server, or why I get this kind of error using Jetty ?

Comment: Few people will be able to help you with the Jetty error if you don't include the actual error in your question ;)

Answer (score 2):

I did not tested it with JBoss, but using a Tomcat as a server it works well:

1. compile your GWT project
2. create a new web application project and add the compiled GWT artefacts , the html and css files to that project
3. create a running configuration for Tomcat and add the newly created web project to that server and start it
4. create a GWT running configuration with the following Dev Mode parameters: -noserver -port 8080 (if you use Tomcat, for JBoss use the JBoss port for web application) and use as startpage: http://127.0.0.1:[WebApplicationPort]/[YourApplilcationHtml] (Depending on your application context in your Tomcat running configuration, the url can differ) and start it

This works for me.

Hope that helps.

Comment: We've used a variation of the above with tomcat for 4+ years, both with classic and super dev modes.